# Generating doxygen comments for swig-generated C# that wraps C++

Tags: c#, c++, doxygen, swig

I have a project written in C++ where I'm using swig to generate some C# wrappers as well. The C++ code uses Doxygen style comments to annotate the classes and functions. Is it possible to get Swig to take those doxygen comments and produce doxygen comments for the C# wrapper classes and functions?

Comment: There exists a doxy2swig.py scripts, which generates a file that you can include in your interface .i file. It is pretty neat

Comment: I'm having trouble getting doxy2swig.py to work with C#. It looks like it's designed to work with Python and a cursory google search didn't yield any results. Any ideas?

Comment: It should work just fine. It generates a `DesiredName.i` file, which can be included using `%include "DesiredName.i"`. Do you get an output?

Comment: Yeah, I get an output.i filled with Python docstrings. Including those in a C# file doesn't seem to do anything. I've added a bounty to this question, if you can show me how to make it work it's yours :)

Comment: Sorry, just erased my last Windows partition - without any possibility for returning.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, SWIG does not parse code comments including Doxygen documentation at all.

There is a SWIG branch in development since a couple of years to enable SWIG to deal with Doxygen comments, but even that currently (AFAIK) only maps them to Java and Python documentation.

The best option currently is therefore to extract the Doxygen documentation from the C++ source code and insert it into the SWIG generated wrapper. To understand how this can be done, here is a brief explanation of what `doxy2swig.py` does (and this is indeed meant for python docstrings):

1. Let Doxygen extract the documentation into its XML format
2. Parse the XML, and reformat into suitable Python docstrings
3. Write `%feature("docstring")` SWIG directives to tell SWIG to attach the docstrings to the wrapped classes and methods.

Basically, something similar can be done for C# as well. I do not know how to do (2) for C#, i.e., how to translate the Doxygen XML output into suitable C# documentation, this you may need to implement yourself (perhaps by modifying the `doxy2swig.py` script).

For (3) there is a neat trick that is sort of documented [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Java_javadoc_comments), noting that the same can also be done for C# using the `%csclassmodifiers` and `%csmethodmodifiers`. These SWIG feature directives are AFAIK used to prepend either `public` or `protected` to C# methods or classes. But they can be hijacked to prepend the extracted documentation (+ the `public` keyword, not to forget). So they effectively allow the same functionality as the `%feature("docstring")` directive for Python.

Finally, I don't know C#, but what is the point of having the Doxygen comments included in the C# wrapper? If you only want to use Doxygen to generate documentation, you can do this from the C++ sources directly, so you don't gain anything. In Python, the docstrings can be displayed as help at runtime, and are used by some IDEs. Does C# have this, too?

Comment: This is pretty much the path I've been going down, so I guess it's nice to have my suspicions confirmed. As for your question: "Finally, I don't know C#, but what is the point of having the Doxygen comments included in the C# wrapper?" I guess I should have been clearer in my question. I'm not so much interested in the comments for C# as I am in the documentation pages they're used to produce. Using the C++ doc strings directly doesn't quite work because many times comments will refer to other functions, and those references (and the hyperlinks) need to point at the appropriate C# functions.

Comment: As of Oct. 2022, there is a merge request which supposedly adds support for verbatim comments translation for C# in https://github.com/swig/swig/pull/1695

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2022, the accepted answer [from m7thon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37871770/7200132) has become outdated. I have started work in the (public) merge request https://github.com/swig/swig/pull/2421, based on the nice prior work from https://github.com/swig/swig/pull/1695, to add support for doxygen comments for SWIG-generated C#.

The current status in the above MR still has quite significant limitations. Also it has not yet been extensively tested. But it can already achieve basic documentation in C# XML format, and may be a good starting point for people in need of a solution.

Comment: Any comments on how we can handle typemaps when porting the doxygen comments from source to target language?

Comment: @Maverickgugu can you explain what you would like to happen with the typemaps? Also, maybe you can better comment on the above pull request, it may be much easier to work with your suggestions there...

Comment: I was aiming for converting C-API doxygen comments to that of Python. I'm currently challenged due to typemaps as it modifies the signature of the interface thereby making C-API doxygen comments inconsistent. I assumed there might be a similar challenge for converting to C#.

Comment: @Maverickgugu your question seems to be very specific to the implementation status of ongoing work in swig. I would highly recommend to discuss that matter in an issue over at swig, and only link to that issue from here.